KQL - Count how many rows are 2hrs less on current row
I need to have a new column which has the count of rows that are 2hrs less than the current row. For example for 2024-03-30T21:15:00Z there are 3 rows that fall into the criteria (2024-03-30T20:15:00Z, 2024-03-30T20:00:00Z, 2024-03-30T19:30:00Z) thus the historical count should be 3.
I wanted to avoid using join because it makes the table very large (I have 25,000 records and it exploded to 280,000). Looking for a better approach on this.


Site    Name    Timestamp
1   User 1  2024-03-30T18:30:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T18:45:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T19:00:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T19:30:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T20:00:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T20:15:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T21:15:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T23:15:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-30T23:30:00Z
1   User 1  2024-03-31T00:00:00Z





Site    Name    Timestamp   HistoricalCount
1   User 1  2024-03-30T18:30:00Z    0
1   User 1  2024-03-30T18:45:00Z    1
1   User 1  2024-03-30T19:00:00Z    2
1   User 1  2024-03-30T19:30:00Z    3
1   User 1  2024-03-30T20:00:00Z    4
1   User 1  2024-03-30T20:15:00Z    5
1   User 1  2024-03-30T21:15:00Z    3
1   User 1  2024-03-30T23:15:00Z    1
1   User 1  2024-03-30T23:30:00Z    1
1   User 1  2024-03-31T00:00:00Z    2




Without using Joins you could test a number of future states (in this case up to nine) and report on that.
let T = datatable(Site:int, Name:string, Timestamp:datetime) [
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T18:30:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T18:45:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T19:00:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T19:30:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T20:00:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T20:15:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T21:15:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T23:15:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T23:30:00Z'),
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-31T00:00:00Z')
];
let LookBack = 2h;
T
| partition by Name (
order by Timestamp asc
| extend TimestampWindow = Timestamp - (LookBack)
| extend Temp1 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 1) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp2 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 2) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp3 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 3) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp4 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 4) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp5 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 5) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp6 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 6) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp7 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 7) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp8 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 8) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend Temp9 = coalesce(toint(prev(Timestamp, 9) >= TimestampWindow), 0)
| extend HistoricCount = Temp1 + Temp2 + Temp3 + Temp4 + Temp5 + Temp6 + Temp7 + Temp8 + Temp9
| project-away Temp*, TimestampWindow
)




Site
Name
Timestamp
HistoricCount




1
User 1
2024-03-30T18:30:00Z
0


1
User 1
2024-03-30T18:45:00Z
1


1
User 1
2024-03-30T19:00:00Z
2


1
User 1
2024-03-30T19:30:00Z
3


1
User 1
2024-03-30T20:00:00Z
4


1
User 1
2024-03-30T20:15:00Z
5


1
User 1
2024-03-30T21:15:00Z
3


1
User 1
2024-03-30T23:15:00Z
1


1
User 1
2024-03-30T23:30:00Z
1


1
User 1
2024-03-31T00:00:00Z
2




I have managed to come up with a solution based on the scan operator - not entirely straight forward.
The basic idea is to keep a dynamic array per row that contains the Timestamp values of all preceding rows. Then you trim all values from the array that are more than 2h in the past. This ended up being tricky - possibly because I don't fully understand the scan operator state logic with multiple steps but here is the code which passes your example:
let T = datatable(Site:int, Name:string, Timestamp:datetime) [
'1', 'User 1', datetime('2024-03-30T18:30:00Z'),
'1', 'User 2', datetime('2024-03-30T18:45:00Z'),
'1', 'User 3', datetime('2024-03-30T19:00:00Z'),
'1', 'User 4', datetime('2024-03-30T19:30:00Z'),
'1', 'User 5', datetime('2024-03-30T20:00:00Z'),
'1', 'User 6', datetime('2024-03-30T20:15:00Z'),
'1', 'User 7', datetime('2024-03-30T21:15:00Z'),
'1', 'User 8', datetime('2024-03-30T23:15:00Z'),
'1', 'User 9', datetime('2024-03-30T23:30:00Z'),
'1', 'User 10', datetime('2024-03-31T00:00:00Z')
];
let LookBack = 2h;
T
| order by Timestamp asc
| scan declare(lookBackArray: dynamic=dynamic([]), lookBackSize: int=0) with (
    step s1: true => lookBackSize=array_length(array_slice(s1.lookBackArray, 
                                                           array_index_of(series_greater(s1.lookBackArray, 
                                                                                         repeat(Timestamp-LookBack, array_length(s1.lookBackArray))
                                                                                        ), 
                                                                          true
                                                                         ),
                                                           -1)
                                                          ),
                     lookBackArray=array_slice(array_concat(s1.lookBackArray, 
                                                            pack_array(Timestamp)
                                                           ),
                                               array_index_of(series_greater(array_concat(s1.lookBackArray, 
                                                                                          pack_array(Timestamp)
                                                                                         ), 
                                                                             repeat(Timestamp-LookBack, array_length(s1.lookBackArray)+1)
                                                                            ),
                                                              true),
                                               -1);
  )
| project Site, Name, Timestamp, HistoricCount=lookBackSize

Output:



Site
Name
Timestamp
HistoricCount




1
User 1
2024-03-30 18:30:00.0000000
0


1
User 2
2024-03-30 18:45:00.0000000
1


1
User 3
2024-03-30 19:00:00.0000000
2


1
User 4
2024-03-30 19:30:00.0000000
3


1
User 5
2024-03-30 20:00:00.0000000
4


1
User 6
2024-03-30 20:15:00.0000000
5


1
User 7
2024-03-30 21:15:00.0000000
3


1
User 8
2024-03-30 23:15:00.0000000
1


1
User 9
2024-03-30 23:30:00.0000000
1


1
User 10
2024-03-31 00:00:00.0000000
2



Explanation:

lookBackSize is the number of records that fall within the LookBack window. Computed from the inside-out:

repeat: We create an array of the same length as the current accumulated lookBackArray (which contains all previous records inside the window so far) containing the current Timestamp minus the LookBack time.
series_greater: We then compare the accumulated lookBackArray array against the fixed current timestamp array. The resulting array basically contains true if the Timestamp in the accumulated window is greater than the current Timestamp minus Lookback (in other words - it's less than LookBack time ago) and false otherwise.
Since we ordered the records by time the comparison array basically starts with a sequence of 0 or more false values (records that are now outside of the lookback window) with the remainder being true
array_index_of: We find the first index that is true (essentially from here on all accumulated Timestamps fall within the lookback period)
array_slice: We take the tail of the accumulated array which we know contains all accumulate Timestamps within the lookback period.
array_length: The length of this slice is what we're interested in.


lookBackArray: We repeat the same computation as for lookBackSize to update the step state, except we also append the current Timestamp to the array.

Lot of repetition and not very maintainable I'm afraid but should do the trick. Might have missed some edge cases.
